# twitter4j filterquery with multiple conditions e.g location and track (GeoLocation and keywords) in processing

Tags: java, twitter, filter, twitter4j

I am wondering if it is possible to filter users location and keywords

```
 double[][] location= location;
 String keywords[] = {"keywords"};

 FilterQuery fq = new FilterQuery();
 fq.locations(location);
 fq.track(keywords);
 twitterStream.filter(fq);
```

these code only seem to filter keywords..

Comment: please read the FAQ on how to ask a question. Your post starts with a question that can be answered yourself by just trying things out, so do so. Google and the APIs/tutorials for the packages you use would be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

Bounding boxes for locations are logical ORs. A locations parameter may be combined with track parameters, but note that all terms are logically ORs, so the query string track=twitter&locations=-122.75,36.8,-121.75,37.8 would match any tweets containing the term Twitter (even non-geo tweets) **OR** coming from the San Francisco area.

Comment: is there any possibility to filter by language ?

Comment: Yes, before 1 month twitter developers decided to add that possibility in twitter API. So twitter4j also support it. just add following: 
`private String[] language = new String[]{"en"};
FilterQuery fq = new FilterQuery();
 fq.track(keywords).lang(language);
 twitterStream.filter(fq);`

Comment: which version of twitter4j is supporting that, i am using twitter4j 3.0.3